# Why is my D3 zoom transform not centering properly?

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, zooming, scale, translate

I'm upgrading my map to v3 of D3 and using the click to zoom transformation outlined in the D3 example code found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590).

My code is nearly identical except that my map has slightly smaller dimensions (564 x 300 instead of 960 x 500). In addition, I have my map nested within a div and off to the top left of my page (though I don't think this matters)

The initial load of my map loads is fine (using black background for distinction currently)

```
// Clear existing map in case there is remnant data.
$("#map").html(null);

var mapWidth = 564;
var mapHeight = 300;

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
                          .scale(mapWidth)
                          .translate([0, 0]);   

var path = d3.geo.path()
                 .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("#map")
               .append("svg")
               .attr("id", "map-svg")
               .attr("width", mapWidth)
               .attr("height", mapHeight);

   svg.append("rect")
    .attr("id", "map-background")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", mapWidth)
    .attr("height", mapHeight)
    .on("click", click);

   // Create placeholders for shapes and labels
   var states = svg.append("g")
                   .attr("transform", "translate(" + mapWidth / 2 + "," + mapHeight / 2 + ")")
                   .attr("id", "states");
```

[image]

However, when a state is clicked, and the click function runs, my transform seems to be off. In my case, the state of Arkansas was clicked (indicated with blue shading)

```
function click(d)
{
   var x = 0,
       y = 0,
       k = 1;

   if (d && centered !== d)
   {
      var centroid = path.centroid(d);
      x = -centroid[0];
      y = -centroid[1];
      k = 4;
      centered = d;      
   }
   else
   {
      centered = null;
   }

   d3.select("#states").selectAll("path")
       .classed("active", centered && function (d) { return d === centered; });

   d3.select("#states").transition()
       .duration(1000)
       .attr("transform", "scale(" + k + ")translate(" + x + "," + y + ")")
       .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
}
```

[image]

My only thought is that my centroid calculations need to be adjusted slightly for the smaller size or different position of the map, but this doesn't seem right either.

How do I make the proper adjustments?

EDIT: I found that if I add a "negative translation" at the end of the transform (translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")) that it gets closer to properly centering on the zoom, but not perfectly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing one of two transforms from [the example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590); but read on for a simpler solution.

The example you're using has two nested transforms. First, a static transform on the outer G element:

```
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
  .append("g")
    .attr("id", "states");
```

This transform serves the same purpose as [projection.translate](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-translate) normally does, but the example is using the translate([0, 0]). (As I said, there will be a simpler solution…)

The second transform is set dynamically on the *inner* G (with id "states") to zoom in:

```
g.transition()
    .attr("transform", "scale(" + k + ")translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
```

Note that the `var g` here refers to the inner G element, because when `g` was defined, there was an `append("g")` that was chained with a second `append("g")`; the variable is thus defined as the second, inner G, rather than the first, outer G.

The resulting SVG looks like this:

```
<g transform="translate(480,250)">
  <g id="states" transform="translate(75.746,-439.514)scale(4,4)">
    …
  </g>
</g>
```

Your derivation is missing the nested, inner G. So when you set the "transform" attribute on your #states G element, you're overwriting the outer transform, giving you this:

```
<g id="states" transform="scale(4)translate(18.936679862557288,-109.8787070159044)">
  …
</g>
```

So, you're missing the static transform, "translate(480,250)".

I'd recommend combining these transforms together. Then you don't need the outer G, and you can :

```
g.transition()
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")"
        + "scale(" + k + ")"
        + "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
```

This also eliminates the need to set the projection’s translate to [0, 0], so you can use the standard translate [width / 2, height / 2] instead. I've [updated the example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590) to do just that!

Comment: I knew I had something out of alignment! Thanks for the update AND simplification. This works like a charm!

Comment: @mbostock could you please have a look on my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750044/how-to-split-multiple-d3-transform-commands-into-separate-statements it's very similar to this one here.