# How to split multiple D3 transform commands into separate statements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some trouble with my **zooming**. I found this zooming with **2x translate** and **1x zoom**:

```
g.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")");
```

This is working. But I want to save the zooming state by using **zoom commands** e.g. So I tried it in the following way:

```
zoom.translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
zoom.scale(k);
zoom.translate([-x, -y]);
g.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + zoom.translate() + ")scale(" + zoom.scale() + ")");
```

But in this way `zoom.translate([width / 2, height / 2]);` is completely ignored  because I've overwritten it.

But how can I use the zoom commands to solve my issue?

### Another idea

How can I write the both translate statements as one. Is this possible somehow?

Some useful links on this:

- https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-group-element-and-d3js
- [stacking transforms in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126127/stacking-transforms-in-d3)
- http://grokbase.com/t/gg/d3-js/1348aqq9bm/d3-transform-an-extension-for-the-transform-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with the following - very creepy - solution. It's working well but for me it looks very ugly and is based on saving the transformation in a special variable:

```
var currentzoomy = d3.transform("translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
zoom.scale(currentzoomy.scale[0]);
zoom.translate(currentzoomy.translate);
```

Is that an OK solution? And maybe someone now has a better idea what my issue was about. =)